# why wont the loop repeat the file creation

Tags: c++, loops

I'm new to c++ and wrote this code to generate 10 1MB files with incremented file names

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    stringstream file_name_ss;

    std::ofstream file;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        file_name_ss << "file_" << i << ".ini";
        string file_name = file_name_ss.str();
        int size = 1024 * 1024 * 1; //~1MB
        file.open( file_name, ios::app);
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            file << "a";
        }
    }
}
```

when I run it the program only one file (file_0.txt) is generated.
is the second loop breaking/escaping the first?

I tried looking online and couldn't find anything that got past the first file

EDIT: I got the loops working(thank you Sam Varshavchik) by adding the line `file.close();` to the inner loop. Here is my updated code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    stringstream file_name_ss;

    std::ofstream file;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        file_name_ss << "file_" << i << ".ini";
        string file_name = file_name_ss.str();
        int size = 1024 * 1024 * 1; //~1MB
        file.open( file_name, ios::app);
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            file << "a";
        file.close();
        }
    }
}
```

But I now have a new problem: now the file names look like this:

[image: files]

not a terrible error but still kind of annoying. I think it has something to do with this part:

```
file_name_ss << "file_" << i << ".ini";
```

Comment: Can you point your finger to exact line of the shown code which you believe closes the first input file, before the second one can be opened. This is a trick question: there isn't one.

Comment: Nitpicking: `1024*1024` is not 1MB but 1MiB :)

Comment: thank you very much. would it be file.close(); ?

Comment: Side note: Are you sure that you want to open the file in append mode (`ios::app`)?

Comment: @cabbose2552: Yes, adding `file.close` would solve one of the several problems your code is having.

Comment: Please do not change your question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers. In particular, do not change the code in the question by applying fixes mentioned in the answer to the code, because that makes the answer useless. You added the line `file.close();` to your question 8 minutes after the existing answer was edited to point out that problem, thereby invalidating that part of the answer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with adding additional information to the bottom of the question in a clearly marked edit, as long as the original question is left intact. In that edit, you can also post your updated code, as long as the original code remains intact.

Comment: I have now updated your question in such a way that it does not invalidate the existing answer.

Comment: The indentation of `file.close();` is misleading. It is part of the inner loop, not the outer loop. However, it should be in the outer loop, otherwise you will close each file one million times instead of only once. Also, you will only write a single byte to each file, because it gets closed immediately afterwards. All further writes will fail, because the file has already been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *two* problems, which are really the same problem but done twice: You only have a single string and file stream object, and those won't be "reset" when the loop iterates.

For example the single `file` object can only be opened *once*. Any attempt to open it again without closing in between will simply fail.

As for the string stream, each iteration will *append* to the file name you attempt to open. For example in the second iteration of the loop you will try to open the file `file_0.inifile_1.ini`. And so on.

The simple solution to both problems? Move the variable definitions *inside* the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    ostringstream file_name_ss;
    file_name_ss << "file_" << i << ".ini";

    std::ofstream file(file_name_ss.str());

    // ... Rest of loop...
}
```

<sub>[Note that the code should really add some error checking.]</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
stringstream file_name_ss;
std::ofstream file;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    file_name_ss << "file_" << i << ".ini";
    string file_name = file_name_ss.str();
    int size = 1; //~1MB
    file.open(file_name, ios::app);
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        file << "a";
    }
    file.close();//close file before open new one 
    file_name_ss.str("");//clear stream
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file after you are done writing to it. Also, your code doesn't clear the previous file name so you just keep adding on to it. Add this to the end of your for loop.

```
file_name_ss.str("");
file.close();
```